# Generate Pseudo Random bits from a string in msword VBA

Tags: vba, random, ms-word, numbers

I need a code in MS Word VB A, I have a sequence of bits as 10110001110000111 .... my interest is how to generate random bit sequence assumes that first generate fourth bit is 1 then the next if I need 3 bits are generated three random bits as 1 0 1 so if need four bits four random bits are generated as 1001. After doing all this if I run again which can generate the bit sequence again.

Comment: As interesting as this is, I'm obligated to ask [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) You should also clarify your question a bit. You're asking for "random" bits that are actually `101` and `1001` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CRC. Not too familiar with VBA, but if you use for example CRC32, then you can generate a good pseudorandom bitstream.

You do need to make a good selection for what is called the polynomial, but if you use the well known ones, the results are very good.

This is coded as C, rather than as VBA, sorry, but from memory VBA makes the relevant operators available.

```
int nextbit( void )
{
    uint32_t seed = 1;

    seed = (seed&0x80000000? 0x04c11db7 : 0) ^ (seed<<1);

    return  seed&1;
}
```

or

```
int nextbit( void )
{
    uint32_t seed = 1;

    seed = (seed&1? 0x82608EDB : 0) ^ (seed>>1);

    return  seed&1;
}
```

Which, believe it or not are both the same polynomial. Just going in different direcetions - the complete polynomial needs to have 2^32 added which is usually considered redundant. The polynomial in use here is CRC-CCITT 32 bit, used for checksumming data.

The second one is probably better, since the first will start with 32 0 before it gets going.

Init seed to any value you want, and a careful choice of polynomial will guarantee that it has a 2^32 cycle before it repeats itself.

Comment: 0x82608EDB == (0x04c11db7 + 2^32)/2, so its the same polynomial.